# Autoscaling policy based on 2 queues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I managed to set an alarm/autoscaling policy that triggers based on messages in an SQS queue. However, I have 2 queues integral to this process - I need my alarm to trigger only when BOTH of the queues meet the trigger requirements. So something like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "messages_not_visible" {
  alarm_name          = "q1"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  ...
  dimensions = {
    QueueName = "q1.fifo", "q2.fifo"
  }
  alarm_actions = [aws_appautoscaling_policy.scale_down_policy.arn]
}
```

This obviously errors out, as it only accepts a string. I tried making 2 separate alarms for those 2 queues, but I don't want my ECS to be scaled down twice because it triggers 2 times. Only when both of the triggers are satisfied. What do I do here?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: @Marcin 
Inappropriate value for attribute "dimensions": element "QueueName": string required.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [CloudWatch Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html) to create an alarm that is based on more than one metric.